# How do I add a line to a file in powershell if it doesn't exist?

Tags: powershell, firefox

First off, I'm pretty new to powershell, and a long time lurker. Please forgive my disgusting formatting.

I'm trying to write some settings to a .js file for Firefox. I've got the first part figured out, but I can't seem to get powershell to accurately check if the string already exists in the file, and then do nothing. Every time this is run, if the file exists, then it just appends the same info the to file.

```
    $newline='pref("network.negotiate-auth.trusted-uris", "domain.com");'
    $jsfile='C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\defaults\pref\policies.js'
    $jsfiledl='http://someserver/repo/windows/policies.js'

    If (!(Test-Path $jsfile)) {
       (New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadFile($jsfiledl, 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\defaults\pref\policies.js')
    } Else {
    If (!(Select-String -Path $jsfile -pattern $newline)){Add-Content $jsfile $newline}
    }
```

Comment: `!(Select-String -Path $jsfile -pattern $newline -SimpleMatch)` select-string uses regex by default. Your search string contains regex metachars

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need is to add the `-SimpleMatch` switch to your `Select-String`.

The reason this doesn't match as a regular expression is due to the parenthesis.  Parenthesis mean grouping in regular expressions, and don't match literal parentheses in you file, resulting in an overall failure to match.

Comment: You are right Matt.   At first I didn't analyze it, just tried the solution interactively.

Comment: Yes, but periods match themselves just fine.

Comment: In _this_ case yes, but the Op should be aware. Your answer makes it seems that the parenthesis are the only thing that _could_ be a miss. A generalized answer about regular expressions is what I was suggesting

Comment: Awesome, did not know regex was natively recognized in powershell. This worked perfect! Thank you!